# RPC response not correct

Tags: go, rpc

I am trying to use a remote procedure which will set a reply in a struct, with a boolean status and a string as next input.
In the procedure, I am setting the boolean status as true and putting a value into input.
But in the client, it gets a false status and empty string.
In Procedure:

```
func(c *Coordinator)MapJob(req mr.MapRequest, reply *mr.MapResponse) error {
    //logic to set up response...
    reply = &mr.MapResponse{
        Status: newStatus,
        Input:  newIn,
    }
    fmt.Printf("[REPLY] %+v\n", reply)

    return nil
}
```

prints `[REPLY] &{Status:true Input:1.txt}`

while in client:

```
err := client.Call("Coordinator.MapJob", req, &reply)
        fmt.Printf("reply from procedure %+v\n", reply)
```

prints:`reply from procedure {Status:false Input:}`

What am I missing here?
I have put the whole code in https://github.com/Brotchu/ProjectMR
The procedure is defined in coordinator, and client in worker.
It may be too much to paste it all in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client structure look like it is only made of zero values (`false` and the empty string).

I think the `client.Call` call do not mutate the reply. And i think this is because `MapJob` doesn't mutate the reply either.

```
reply = &mr.MapResponse{
        Status: newStatus,
        Input:  newIn,
    }
```

Should be

```
reply.Status = newStatus
reply.Input =  newIn
```

Comment: that worked. so , as i understand, when i do reply = &mr.MapResponse{}  i am putting a new address into reply, and the actual one that comes from client is not mutated. is that the right way to put it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the reply value that passed during the call, so replace

```
reply = &mr.MapResponse{
    Status: newStatus,
    Input:  newIn,
}
```

With

```
*reply = mr.MapResponse{
    Status: newStatus,
    Input:  newIn,
}
```